# What's better background structure for GridView

Tags: android

I'm developing an application at Android 4 who has many Tabs(ActionBar.Tab) and each Tab has a GridView whicth shows approximately 30 images (ImageView). Each image throws other activities when clicked. When execution of activity ends the system shows the Tab previously selected. This is the scenery for each Tab. 
The images for each Tab are load from database and put in a singleton List. Then exists only one List for images of application and the list loads every changing of Tab. 
When I access another Tab it gets a lot of time to load my list of images and put in GridView. I already reduced the size of my image in Bitmap, but I don't found a good solution. 
I would like know if you have knowledge else structure I could use.

Thanks.

Marcelo Araujo

Answer (score 0):

*"The images for each Tab are load from database and put in a singleton List"*

Bad idea since you can get OOM.

Please read [Displaying Bitmaps Efficiently](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html) article.

Comment: How do you do the transport of images? Do you read each image from database each utilization? For example, I could use LruCache, but I need calculate the size of each image before. My problem is not out-of-memory, but the slowness at tab transition.